# Nautilus hangs in /proc

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I am using nautilus 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7 on Ubuntu 14.04. 
Yesterday I realized  that this program comes with a unwanted feature, namely that it freezes up my entire system when I enter /proc, leaving only the option to do a hard reboot. The system doesn't freeze when I enter /proc from Terminal.

I've seen bug reports from 2005 and 2011 mentioning this bug, but nothing regarding how it can be fixed.

It's a minor inconvenience but if anyone knows how a fix to this problem (other than changing file manager), I would be very grateful :-)!